# How to use oncopy in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

Is there a way to make this work in IE? It works in Chrome and Firefox.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div oncopy="alert('text copied')">
      Copy me
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which IE? Works in IE9

Comment: I'm testing on IE 10.0.9200.16686